# Gradle Exception in build apk in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I got this exception

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
> ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. Problems reading data from Binary store
> in C:\Users\Bos we
> Tol\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle7580153242877513998.bin offset 394857
> exists? true

but before 2 days I was run it successfully

Comment: Exit your app and and run flutter clean then run flutter pub get

and can you tell me the your grade file compilesdkvirson and androidsdkverion

Comment: 29 for both , but the clean is not the right way

Comment: Can you try this change **compileSdkVersion 28, minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 30**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by one of:

1. Change the gradle version to `6.7-all` by change `distributionUrl` in path `<YOUR FLUTTER PROJECT>/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to be like:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

2. Change the jdk version to `11` by install it and change `JAVA_HOME` in env. vars.

Answer (score 0):

this issue solved by upgrading the gragle from
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip

to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip